# Generate url in javascript file

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, grails

I would like to know, which is the best way to write an url in an external javascript file.
Example:
I have a javascript which execute an ajax call like:

```
$(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        $('#content').html($.get('/my-controller/myaction'));
    });
});
```

In this case I have to hard code the url for the controller in my javascript file.
I'm using grails, and it have a nice way to create the urls, and I would like to use it (in case a controller change url I don't have to search all over the javascript files to change them)
What can be the best approach to do it?
Create a controller to serve a view that is a javascript file with all the url needed can be a good solution?
Is there a better way?

Comment: You could drop the URL into an attribute on an easy-to-find tag in the document (like the `<body>` tag), so that your JavaScript can fetch it when it needs to. Having the JavaScript be dynamically generated is not a good idea, because then browsers can't cache it.

Comment: @Pointy - It depends on what the exact name of the JS file is and the cache control information it has on it. There's nothing inherently un-cacheable about a generated file.

Comment: @cdeszaq true, but if it's OK to cache it then the "dynamic" generation should be just a build-time operation.  Otherwise the behavior of the system is unpredictable.

Comment: In this particular instance, where the controller name changing is the issue, yes, a build-time creation is fine. But there are _lots_ of other ways to have much more dynamic responses that are still highly cacheable. Per-user comes to mind as one possibility, or simply using a query string or a timestamped URL. All of these are highly cacheable and still very dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about coding url inside your html instead ?

If the click trigger is a link simply use the href attribute :

```
<a href="/my-controller/myaction" id="myButton">Click</a>

$(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('url');
        $('#content').html($.get(url));
    });
});
```

And if the click trigger is a button or something else , use the data-X attribute :

```
<button id="myButton" data-url="/my-controller/myaction">Click</button>

$(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        $('#content').html($.get(url));
    });
});
```

It nicely separate JS and data and could be usefull (at least for the link) when JS is disabled.

Comment: good! but the use of 'data-url' doesn't create any problem in the page? with the browsers? does IE explode if I use it???

Comment: should just break the xhtml / html 4 validation if you don't use an html5 doctype